# Are Clustered Index Usage Stats skewed since they are referenced in Non-Clustered Keys?

Tags: sql-server, index, dmv

When using tools like SP_BlitzIndex and looking at usage stats for indexes. Would clustered index usage be skewed in any way since they are secret keys in all non-clustered indexes and would be read more often than not?

Trying to determine if a table has the correct clustered index, it's read usage is high but looking at how data is being accessed, I don't see a lot of direct joins utilizing the clustered index column that would lead me to believe the usage numbers.

Answer (score 7):

The `user_lookups` column of `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` is a count of clustered index key lookups (a.k.a. bookmark lookups). This indicates a data row retrieved via a non-clustered index using the clustered index key row locator. The separate `user_seeks` and `user_scans` columns for a clustered index count the number of times the CI was used directly.

These columns allow you to determine how the clustered index is being used in query plans.

Comment: Thanks Dan, appreciate the feedback